# .json fie handling in python3

Tags: python, json

So, I've been trying to load a json file using json.load. It is the simplest, most basic code in the world but this is the error that is being thrown followed by the code and then a snippet of the .json file (in case there is a formatting issue):

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = json.load(input_file)
  File /usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from     None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Code:

```
    import json
    from pprint import pprint

    input_file = open("chennai.recent.02dec2015.jsons",'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')


    data = json.load(input_file)

    pprint (data)
```

.json snippet:

```
{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "#Chennai Floods Leave Thousands Stranded, More Rain Expected For Coming Days #jobs #500K #: India has deployed... "is_quote_status": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "id": 672203575703965696, "favorite_count": 0
```

Comment: The `text` field doesn't appear to be closed; it's an invalid JSON snippet!

Comment: add `",`  at the end of `"#Chennai ....",`.